# Cookies are not stored

Tags: php, cookies

Hello I can't create cookies. I tried different variations but still when I try to echo there's nothing... These variables what I try to set as cookies I can echo I mean $usermail, $row["username"] stores data because I echo them before I am trying to set cookies. What's wrong with my code? Btw. I know that I must replace "mydomain.com" haha... ;)

```
setcookie("usermail", $usermail, time() + (60 * 60 * 24));
setcookie("username", $row["username"], time() + (60 * 60 * 24)); 
setcookie("TestCookie", $value, time()+3600);
setcookie("usermail", $usermail, time() + (60*60*24*30), '/dev/', '.mydomain.com');
setcookie("usermail", $usermail, time() + (60*60*24*30), '/', '.mydomain.com');
```

Comment: Why do you think the cookies aren't being stored?

Comment: Because when I try to echo there's nothing. $a = $_COOKIE["usermail"]; echo $a;

Comment: Did you do that in the same script invocation or after loading a new page?

Comment: cookies won't be in `$_COOKIE[]` on the server until a round trip.

Comment: <php> code is above HTML. I even try to if(isset($_COOKIE["usermail"])) but also it shows echo in "else" section

Comment: @developerwjk yes I know. I also tried to set session using cookies but nothing happens.